# Google Bookmarks are not saved

Tags: google-bookmarks

Google Bookmarks I enter are frequently not saved. This has happened for the past few weeks.

I am using mostly Chrome, on Windows 7; the same phenomenon happened while using Firefox as well. I have observed this using at least 3 different computers, from different locations and at any time of the day. The absence of the bookmarks entered but not saved was checked at several times after entering.

I emphasise this is a question about **[Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/)** and not about *Chrome bookmarks*, nor about the relationship between the two.